# the url not works with api 15 & 16

Tags: android, android-studio, url

the url does not work with the emulator api 15 and 16 , it's works with api > 17

Inside OnCreate

```
String url = Information.URL_AllPosts + title;
        URLEncoder.encode(url);
        ShowPosts(url);
```

ShowPosts

```
private void ShowPosts(String url)
    {
        rv_posts = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_posts);
        rv_posts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Messages.this);
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url.replace(" ", "%20"), null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    for(int x = 0 ; x < response.length() ; x++)
                    {
                        item_messages.add(new Item_Messages(response.getJSONObject(x).getString("id"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("message"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("photo"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("date"),response.getJSONObject(x).getString("type")));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                rv_posts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Messages.this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
                adapter_messages = new Adapter_Messages(Messages.this, item_messages);
                rv_posts.setAdapter(adapter_messages);
                rv_posts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Messages.this, "Error Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

how can I solve this problem??

Comment: I dont see an url. Your post should have started with it.

Comment: problem solved just added , String url = Information.URL_AllPosts + encode(title);
        encode(url,"utf-8");